# Python and sqlite- load tweets

Tags: python, sqlite, twitter, urllib2

Working/learning on loading a set of tweets into a sqlite db in Python 2.7 to then do some queries. But can't seem to get the data to read in.

I can create the db, create the table, but when I go to read the tweets, parse and load- it (seems) it is not populating the table.

Of the many possible fields in each tweet, I am only trying to capture six.

My code is:

```
#create database works fine
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('twitter.db')
c = conn.cursor()

import urllib2
tweets=urllib2.urlopen("http://rasinsrv07.cstcis.cti.depaul.edu/CSC455/assignment4.txt")
tweets.readline()

#create table: works fine
c.execute("CREATE TABLE Tweet(created_at, id, text, source,  in_reply_to_user_ID,retweet_Count)")

#Loads variables & data in table: Not loading. I think this is my problem here.
for elt in tweets:
    currentRow = elt[:-1].split(", ")
    insert = """insert into Tweet values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')""" % ("created_at", "id", "text", 'source', 'in_reply_to_user_ID', 'retweet_Count')
print insert

conn.commit()

#tried to see the table
read_tweets = """SELECT * from Tweet """
c.fetchall()

#tried again to see the table. Must be no data in the table
read_tweets = """SELECT * from Tweet """
rows = c.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print row
```

Comment: You have to execute every SQL line (You only do the create one.) You also need to read the [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) docs. You're missing some basic idioms that would make your code a lot cleaner.

Comment: Actually, your code is pretty crazy. You seem to be missing the idea of how passing and using data works.